# LZ4 module not recognized in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, lz4

I successfully installed LZ4 in Ubuntu but still in Python while running this command:

```
import lz4
```

I am getting error no module found .

Comment: you should install via: `pip install lz4`

Comment: Did you apt-get install "lz4" or "python-lz4"? The latter package should be the one you need for use from Python. http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/vivid/python-lz4